# How to retrieve multiple objects from PostgreSQL using a single JsonPath

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jsonpath

Given the following JSON example:

```
{
    "root": {
        "child-1": {
            "grandchild-1": "value1",
            "grandchild-2": "value2",
            "grandchild-3": "value3"
        },
        "child-2": {
            "grandchild-4": "value4",
            "grandchild-5": {
                "grandgrandchild-1": "value5"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to build a PostgreSQL query, using (one single) json-path that would return multiple object values?

E.g., [value3, value5]

The closest I came to is the following query:

```
select jsonb_path_query(resp_json, '$.*.child-1.grandchild-3'),
       jsonb_path_query(resp_json, '$.*.child-2.grandchild-5.grandgrandchild-1')
from req_resp_body;
```

The obvious issue with this approach is that it requires one jsonb_path_query function call for each object. Given that the incoming nr. of objects is indefinite, this is unusable.

**Notes**:

- The '*' instead of 'root' is on purpose, since the user of the query might not know the actual root name

Comment: They just appear to be two arbitrary values you've selected. It isn't that you want multiple results matching one path, you want to be able to specify multilple paths? How would that be different from calling json_path_query multiple times?

Comment: I need to be able to allow the user to send a list of paths. Other than concatenating them all in a single json-path (which then should be passed to the repo method), I see no other way to produce a dynamic query that would retrieve multiple paths.